# instance_variable_get won't accept valid instance variable name

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

```
@object0 = "bars"
@object1 = "foobs"

query0 = "@object" + "0"
puts instance_variable_get(query0) #=> bars

puts instance_variable_get(:@object1) #=> foobs

query1 = ":" + "@object" + "1"
puts instance_variable_get(query1) #=> ':@object1' is not allowed as an instance variable name!
```

The problem is definitely the colon, despite it being the only way you can reference instance variables in the global scope. I think the instance_variable_get method is being too clever for its own good. Is there anyway to force it into accepting an instance variable it regards as invalid? Any work arounds? At first I thought I might be something do to with the fact I was handing a simple string to the method, but as you can see, the first two uses of instance_variable_get work perfectly, and they use strings.

Answer (score 3):

As Some Guy already points out, an instance variable must start with `@`, not `:`.

```
query1 = "@object" + "1"
puts instance_variable_get(query1)
```

or (redundantly),

```
query1 = ("@object" + "1").to_sym
puts instance_variable_get(query1)
```

Answer (score 1):

:@object1 is a symbol.

":" + "@object" + "1" is a string.

It's telling you that you can't have an instance variable name that starts with ":"

Comment: Clearly you didn't even read my question. This isn't even an answer, so make it a comment. Don't know who voted this up..

Comment: It's an answer.  I was pointing out that your first two calls to get_instance_variable aren't both using Strings.  One uses a string, one uses a symbol.  They're not the same thing and that's where you seem to be running into trouble.  As for instance variable names starting with ":", there is no workaround for this, and I don't quite see in what way that's causing you problems.

Comment: @Starkers Indeed, this is half of the correct answer.  The other half--what change you need to make to your code to get it to work--is in sawa's answer.